# Cannot get Hot Module working in Atom

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, atom-editor, hot-module-replacement

I've installed everything what I need (webpack, webpack-server), confingured my webpack.config.js and package.json, still the **localhost:8080** does not render on safe. Neither does it render on **localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html** on safe. On manual reload it renders perfectly.

**package.json**:

[image]

**webpack.config.js**[image]

**npm run dev** executes successfully but I also have to reload the page manually after I make some changes in my index.html which is in the parent folder. Also, I always have to run **webpack** manually in my cmd when I change my .js file. Hot loading should also take care of this if I'm correct.

Let me also add that the app is recompiling when I run **CTRL+s** but it doesn't actually recompile.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with live reloading on changes. Try to change link to bundle.js in your index.html
    `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`
If you look in console output after npm start there will be same like
    `webpack output is served from /`
Dev-server takes bundle from root directory of your project, not from /js/bundle.js

Comment: You gotta be kidding me right, +25 immediately. Have spent 16 hours to get this fixed. By the way how should have I known that the bundle is taken from the root? Why isn't there some kind of warnning...

Comment: There is nothing about this behavior of webpack-dev-server in documentation. It's strangely that if we use `webpack --watch` bundle.js is created in `output.path` directory, but `dev-server` creates own bundle in root (but you can't see this bundle in file manager, magic).